# Flutter TextField Causing NullPointerException

Tags: android, flutter, nullpointerexception, flutter-layout, textfield

Any idea why the `TextField` in Flutter code below is causing the `NullPointerException` shown?

Code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TextField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
W/System.err(13600): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.ClipData.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
W/System.err(13600):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.getPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:197)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.content.ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:247)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:274)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:24)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:81)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:230)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/System.err(13600):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
W/System.err(13600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
W/System.err(13600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(13600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err(13600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a stateful widget for Textfield and textformfield. probably thats what causing the error.